# How to update a column based on counts from another table?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I need to update the table actor, column numCharacters, depending on how many times each actor's actorID shows up on the characters table.

I have the following code:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()

statement = 'UPDATE actor SET numCharacters = (SELECT count(*) FROM characters GROUP BY actorID)';

cursor.execute(statement);

connection.commit()
```

Does anyone know how I could complete it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from your sub query will return multiple row, so the update statement won't know which row to update. Try updating your query to this:

```
UPDATE actor a
SET a.numCharacter = (
  SELECT count(*) 
  from characters c
  WHERE actorId = a.id
  Group by actorId
);
```

[db fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWzfWjVzDkJPsbLdDkha2Y/1)